# Strange Table View Header issue when using Three20 TTTableViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, uikit, three20

I am building a `TTTableViewController` subclass based on Three20 TTCatalog sample. In there they have defined a subclass of `TTTableViewController` which has search functionality, called `SearchTextController`, and it has a search bar appear in the table view header.

Here's what their `loadView` method looks like:

```
- (void)loadView {
  [super loadView];

  TTTableViewController* searchController = [[[TTTableViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
  searchController.dataSource = [[[MockSearchDataSource alloc] initWithDuration:1.5] autorelease];
  self.searchViewController = searchController;
  self.tableView.tableHeaderView = _searchController.searchBar;
}
```

I tried to re implement the same kind of functionality in my own subclass of TTTableView. The problem is that I cannot get the search bar to appear.

Running these in `loadView` of TTCatalog SearchTestController (after the last line)

```
 NSLog(@"_searchController.searchBar address %@",_searchController.searchBar.description);
 NSLog(@"self.tableView.tableHeaderView address %@",self.tableView.tableHeaderView.description);
```

yields the same memory address for the layer (meaning the view got set correctly)

```
2012-07-03 12:00:02.326 TTCatalog[53493:f803] _searchController.searchBar address <UISearchBar: 0x6a5c940; frame = (0 0; 320 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x6a5ca40>>
2012-07-03 12:00:02.327 TTCatalog[53493:f803] self.tableView.tableHeaderView address <UISearchBar: 0x6a5c940; frame = (0 0; 320 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x6a5ca40>>
```

When I run the same NSLogs in my app, I get this:

```
2012-07-03 11:41:54.900 myApp[51991:f803] _searchController.searchBar address <UISearchBar: 0x6a43c20; frame = (0 0; 320 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x6a43ce0>>
2012-07-03 11:41:54.901 myApp[51991:f803] self.tableView.tableHeaderView address <UISearchBar: 0x6a43c20; frame = (0 0; 320 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x6a43ce0>>
```

The layers have the same memory address in my app as well, but the search bar is not visible in the table view header. Is there something else I am missing here?